# Swift - Pass struct array through block and retrieve members

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i have a completion block that hands an struct array of data to another viewcontroller.

This data is received in viewDidLoad like:

```
  var packArray = [Any]()// the block is returning Any

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
             BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Pack", sender: self) { (result) in     
                  self.packArray = [result]
             }
    }
```

printing this self.packArray returns the following all on one line and i now have no idea how i can extract the data.

```
[[static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk00", description: "This is some text", title: "Not a murderer", image: <PFFile: 0x60000005fc80>, id: "rHITAAHJYk"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk01", description: "This is some text", title: "Addiction", image: <PFFile: 0x600000240300>, id: "uGHHpPF89e"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk02", description: "This is some text", title: "Towels are noisy", image: <PFFile: 0x600000240570>, id: "PeM7hJ4sih"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk03", description: "This is some text", title: "Class action", image: <PFFile: 0x6000002407e0>, id: "LoSXT2PFoS"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk04", description: "This is some text", title: "Beer", image: <PFFile: 0x600000240a50>, id: "vxEsd13twt"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk05", description: "This is some text", title: "Not again...", image: <PFFile: 0x600000240cc0>, id: "JNqaAgtdRb"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk06", description: "This is some text", title: "Foreign cars", image: <PFFile: 0x600000240f30>, id: "Hb16TDXGbz"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk07", description: "This is some text", title: "Skin problems", image: <PFFile: 0x6000002411a0>, id: "MUYDMnJCrU"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk08", description: "This is some text", title: "Junk food", image: <PFFile: 0x600000241410>, id: "yowAfJlcmr"), static ParseStarterProject_Swift.BuildArray.(buildArrayFromQuery (queryForCollection : Swift.String, sender : __ObjC.UIViewController, completeBlock : (Any) -> ()) -> ()).(collectionStruct #1)(name: "pk09", description: "This is some text", title: "Delusion", image: <PFFile: 0x600000241680>, id: "TiLAKBPmaD")]]
```

previously i was using:

```
cell.labelCell.text = self.packArray[indexPath.item].packDescription
```

but this now returns that there is no member packDescription. I probably could go and use string handling and create a mess but there must be a better way of getting the data as an actual array.  i know I'm casting it as Any but couldn't figure out another way to get the data from a struct array through a completion block.

----- EDIT ----

In the class where the array is created there is a struct, and array from struct
the result is passed through the completeBlock as Any

```
class func buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: String,
       sender: UIViewController, 
       completeBlock: @escaping (_ result: Any) -> Void) {

    struct collectionStruct {
        var name : String
        var description : String
        var title : String
        var image : PFFile
        var id: String
    }

        var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()
```

this is then created from a PFQuery, and the resultant array is passes back through the completion handler

```
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

if error != nil {
    print(error!)

} else if let packs = objects {


    for object in packs {

        print(fromName)

        print(object)

        let arrayName = object.object(forKey: fromName) as! String
        let arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: fromDescription) as! String
        let arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: fromTitle) as! String
        let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: fromImage) as! PFFile
        let arrayID = object.objectId as String!

        collectionArray.append(collectionStruct(name: arrayName, description: arrayDescription, title: arrayTitle, image: arrayImage, id: arrayID!))
    }

}


completeBlock(result: collectionArray)

})
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. What type of object does the array actually contain?

Comment: Apologies, PFFile and String. i will edit post with some more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the result of the query to the desired type. If you make packArray an optional, you could assign it directly using

```
var packArray: [collectionStruct]?

self.packArray = result as? [collectionStruct]
```

With that code, if result can't be cast to the correct array type, self.packArray will contain nil.

Or you could use optional binding:

```
var packArray: [collectionStruct] = []
```

...

```
if structsArray = result as [collectionStruct] {
  self.packArray = structsArray
}
```

You should define packArray outside of viewDidLoad:

```
var packArray: [collectionStruct] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
    BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Pack", 
     sender: self) { 
      (result) in 
      if structsArray = result as [collectionStruct] {
        self.packArray = structsArray
     }
}
```

Your code defines a local variable packArray inside viewDidLoad, which confuses things. I advise against using an instance variable and a local variable with the same name.

Comment: Thank you this looks like it should work,  There is still a slight problem, as the completion block is returning (_ Result: (Any) it is returning "Any is not convertible to ...collectionStruct"  as collectionstruct is not a Type i don't think it can be passed through the completion handler.

Comment: also like collectionStruct is defined in the class where the completion block is.  in this class where we set packArray there is no collectionStruct

Comment: Do you have (or need) an initializer for the `struct`?

Comment: im not sure about the init.  i don't think so as I'm trying to pass an array that is made of structs, there is just not Type that allows this to happen.

Comment: You can indeed cast `any` to `[collectionStruct]`. Any mean any type, class or struct. An array is a form of struct.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Duncan C for his input, ill mark your answer as correct i just wanted to share how i tweaked it to get it working.

Defined the struct outside the class, which let me use [collectionStruct] in the completion handler.

```
struct collectionStruct {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var title : String
    var image : PFFile
    var id: String
}

class BuildArray: UICollectionViewController {

    class func buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: String, 
                  sender: UIViewController, 
                    completeBlock: @escaping (_ result: [collectionStruct]) -> Void) {
```

then return the array after the query

```
completeBlock(collectionArray)
```

and then in the other class as Duncan C suggested

```
if let structsArray = result as? [collectionStruct] {
     self.packArray = structsArray
}
```

this still trows a warning:

```
"non option expression type [collectionStruct] used in check for optionals"
```

so ill see what i can do here.