# Create an array of Struct arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, uicollectionview

I have a query that builds a Struct array from some objects.  I want to append multiple of these structs into a single array so that i can use it populate a collectionview that is nested inside a collectionview.  Im not sure this is the best idea but its all I've got a the moment.

So my Struct is:

```
struct CollectionStruct {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var title : String
    var image : PFFile
    var id: String
}
```

In my viewcontroller the variable to hold the struct is thus:

```
var packArray : [CollectionStruct] = []
var partArray : [CollectionStruct] = []

var packId = ""
```

So below what I'm doing is using an item of the previously created packArray to query the DB and build my partArray.  Because i want to do this multiple times and append the partArray into a larger parent array i was thinking of using a for loop like:

```
var i  = 0

for item in self.packArray as [AnyObject] {

    self.packId = self.packArray[i].id

        BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Part", selectedPackID: self.packId, delegateSender: "DownloadPart", completeBlock: { (result) in

            self.partArray = result

            // append this to an array of partArray????

        })
}
```

I don't even know where to start with this.  Is it a bad idea?

essentially what i thought was to call this parent array in cellforitem maybe something like:

```
innerCell.imageCell.image = parentArray[indexPath.item].partArray[indexPath.item].image
```

but i could be way off.

----- EDIT -----

so i can use a multidimensional array inside the closure once self.partArray is set:

```
self.partArray = result
    var parentArray = [[self.partArray]]
        parentArray.append([self.partArray])
```

but this is unusable outside the closure.  How to declare this multidimensional array before self.partArray is set?

------- EDIT -------

Looking into globals for this at the moment.

```
class GlobalPartArray {
    private init() { }
    static let sharedInstance = GlobalPartArray()
    var globalPartArray = [CollectionStruct]()
}
class GlobalParentArray {
    private init() { }
    static let sharedInstance = GlobalParentArray()
    var globalParentArray = [[GlobalPartArray]]()
}
```

then inside closure:

```
GlobalPartArray.sharedInstance.globalPartArray = result
      //can not convert [CollectionStruct] to [GlobalPartArray]
GlobalParentArray.sharedInstance.globalParentArray.append(GlobalPartArray.sharedInstance.globalPartArray)
```

but it throws an error when trying to convert.  I obviously need to convert this data somehow before appending to the GlobalParentArray.

Comment: What happened when you _tried_ it?

Comment: i couldn't even figure out how to create an array that would hold multiple struct arrays.

Comment: An array of multiple CollectionStructs is a `[CollectionStruct]`, as I think you already know. Well, an array of multiple _arrays_ of CollectionStruct would be a `[[CollectionStruct]]`. No problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Pass struct array through block and retrieve members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434213/swift-pass-struct-array-through-block-and-retrieve-members)

Comment: you should always append and not set the `partArray`, because the `BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery` look like async call

Comment: in async call always best to use append? i will look into it thank you